# Boolean type not read in?

Tags: java

I am doing a project in Java for my COSC 117 class and I get an error on my code saying that my boolean type of "done" is never read in. I cannnot figure out how to fix this. Thank you.

```
import java. util.Scanner;
public class PlayCraps {

     /**
      * This program will play the game of craps. The user will roll the dice and if it is a 7 or 11,
      * they win. If the first roll is a 2, 3 or 12; however, they lose. If it is neither, the user
      * keeps rolling until they roll their first number again or a 7. If they roll their first number
      * they win, if they roll a 7, they lose. The program will then ask the user if they want to play 
      * again
      * Programmer: Ryan Mitchell
      * Date: November 19, 2010
      */

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String answer1;
        double firstRoll;
        double makeRoll;
        int totalWins=0;
        int totalLoses=0;
        String answer2;
        boolean done=false;

        System.out.println("If you would like to see the rules of craps type yes, otherwise type no");
        answer1 = keyboard.next();

        if (answer1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            System.out.println("You will roll the dice at least one time. If the first roll is a 7 or 11 you win");
            System.out.println("If the first roll is a 2, 3 or 12; however, you lose.") ;
            System.out.println("If it is neither, you keep rolling until you roll the first number again or a 7. ");
            System.out.println("If you roll the first number you win, if you roll a 7, you lose. ");
            System.out.println("The program will then ask the you if you want to play again");
        }
        System.out.println("Let's play craps");

        do 
        {
            firstRoll=Dice.roll();
            System.out.println("Your first roll is " + firstRoll);
            if (firstRoll == 7|| firstRoll==11) 
            {
                System.out.println("Winner!");
                totalWins++;
            }
            else if (firstRoll == 2 || firstRoll == 3 || firstRoll == 12) 
            {
                System.out.println("Loser!");
                totalLoses++;
            }
            else
            {
                done = false;
                while (done=false)
                { 
                    System.out.println("Now you have to roll your first number before you roll a 7");
                    makeRoll=Dice.roll();
                    System.out.println("You rolled a " + makeRoll);

                    if (makeRoll == firstRoll)
                    {
                        done = true;
                        totalWins++;
                        System.out.println("Winner!");
                    }
                    else if (makeRoll==7)
                    {
                        done = true;
                        totalLoses++;
                        System.out.println("Loser!");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Type yes to play again");
            answer2=keyboard.next();

        } while (answer2.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

        System.out.println("You won " +totalWins +" games");
        System.out.println("You lost " +totalLoses +" games");
    }
}

public class Dice {
    public static double roll() {
        double num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
        double num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
        return num1 + num2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You got ***way*** bigger problems than your bool not being "read in". Indentation, you know that word? That means **more** than 1 space per indent. It also means that there shouldn't be two `}` on the same line etc. I've fixed it for now, next time use a code block.

Comment: Thank you, but when I run this program if the first roll is not a 2 3 7 or 12 it just says "type yes to play again" instead of keep rolling until you roll your first number or a 7.

Comment: By the way, why are you using doubles? :)

Comment: Haha it's my first class and I don't know what I'm doing some of the time. I tried to use integers but I somehow got an error message so I left it as doubles haha.

Comment: Was it an error in `int num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);`? If so, casting with `(int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1)` should fix it. Casting (int) truncates the double.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this:

```
while (done=false)
```

See any problem here? I won't tell you since this is homework.

Answer (score 1):

Change `while (done=false)` to `while (!done)`.

The first performs an assignment.

Comment: Thank you, the program runs now. But how would I change the program so the user has to enter a string of "yes" instead of the loop repeating automatically?

Comment: @Ryan, From what I see in your code, it does that already with `while (answer2.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));`

Comment: I want to program to say before each time it rolls the dice to say "press enter to simulate a roll" or something like that, but I don't know how to do that. Right now the program will do it automatically. This is an example run as soon as I say I do or do not want to read the rules

Comment: If you would like to see the rules of craps type yes, otherwise type no
no
Let's play craps
Your first roll is 10.0
Now you have to roll your first number before you roll a 7
You rolled a 8.0
Now you have to roll your first number before you roll a 7
You rolled a 5.0
Now you have to roll your first number before you roll a 7
You rolled a 7.0
Loser!
Type yes to play again

Comment: You can put a keyboard.next() at the bottom of the while(!done) loop to pause before rolling :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a *warning*, not an error.  However, I believe the message is indicating that the first time you set the value of `done` to false when you declare the variable, the value is not used since you set it to false again later in the code without ever reading in the first value.  This is often evidence of a mistake, hence the helpful warning.  You should still be able to compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

not the answer to your original question but this line:

```
while (done=false)
```

should probably be

```
while (done==false)
```

in java the = operator is used for assignment and the == operator is used for equivalence comparison.